# Parallelise a Shell script without waiting for a batch to finish

Tags: shell, parallel-processing

I would like to run commands in parallel across the multiple processors of my computer. I can do so using,

```
#!/bin/bash

./hello<params1.txt &
./hello<params2.txt &
wait
./hello<params3.txt &
./hello<params4.txt &
```

where the params files are parameters that I pass to the executable `hello'.

However the above code waits for *both* the first two commands to finish before proceeding to the second two. Since the commands I want to run have very variable runtimes, I would like to be able to allow whichever process (on a particular processor) finishes early to proceed to the next command *without* waiting for the other command within the batch to finish.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If all four processes can be safely executed concurrently. Then perhaps you should let Linux (by removing `wait`) or GNU Parallel ( https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) take care of scheduling

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question until you explain what the constraints are. Can all 4 run in parallel? If 2 finishes first, can 3 and 4 both run before 1 finishes? And if so, can they in parallel with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired queue behavior, (but not necessarily the CPU assigning),  can be made to work with [command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) like so:

```
{ ./hello<params1.txt && ./hello<params3.txt ; } &
{ ./hello<params2.txt && ./hello<params4.txt ; }
```

Demo of something like the above:

```
{ { echo a && sleep 2 && echo b ; } & 
  { echo c && sleep 1 && echo d ; } } | tr '\n' ' ' ; echo
```

Output:

```
a c d b
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot allocate jobs to CPUs, and create your own per-CPU job queue.

You could implement a script where you create some sort of job list being fed (say, to a FIFO), with separate worker processes launched in the background reading jobs one at a time (i.e. from said FIFO), executing the job and waiting for it to finish before moving to the next one until no further job is available.  Your main script would then wait for these worker background processes (all executing in parallel), and exit once the last one has finished.

With this you would control how many jobs run at a time, but the OS scheduler will decide how many CPUs to allocate to each, and one job might itself be parallel and use more than one CPU.